# Unable to start . System.err: Calling js method onCreate failed

Tags: android, windows-10, nativescript, emulation

I use this command: `tns run android --device Pixel_2_API_29` to run my NativeScript project on android emulator, but I get this result:

```
Skipping node_modules folder! Use the syncAllFiles option to sync files from this folder.
Searching for devices...
Starting Android emulator with image Pixel_2_API_29
Waiting for emulator device initialization...
Your application will be deployed only on the device specified by the provided index or identifier.
Running webpack for Android...
clean-webpack-plugin: C:\Users\m\Desktop\JS\NativeScript\new\conFusion\platforms\android\app\src\main\assets\app\**\* has been removed.
File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...

webpack is watching the files…

Hash: 74cf71392c2a31059459
Version: webpack 4.27.1
Time: 8985ms
Built at: 06/13/2019 10:46:07 AM
                                                              Asset       Size   Chunks             Chunk Names
                                   App_Resources/Android/app.gradle  556 bytes           [emitted]
                 App_Resources/Android/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml   1.33 KiB           [emitted]
    App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/background.png   3.42 KiB           [emitted]
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png    6.8 KiB           [emitted]
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/logo.png   32.4 KiB           [emitted]
    App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-ldpi/background.png   1.31 KiB           [emitted]
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png   3.23 KiB           [emitted]
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-ldpi/logo.png   9.95 KiB           [emitted]
    App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/background.png   1.89 KiB           [emitted]
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png   3.42 KiB           [emitted]
          App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/logo.png   15.8 KiB           [emitted]
App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-nodpi/splash_screen.xml  304 bytes           [emitted]
   App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/background.png   5.26 KiB           [emitted]
         App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/icon.png   10.4 KiB           [emitted]
         App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xhdpi/logo.png     54 KiB           [emitted]
  App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/background.png   10.3 KiB           [emitted]
        App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/icon.png   20.3 KiB           [emitted]
        App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxhdpi/logo.png    116 KiB           [emitted]
 App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/background.png   3.87 KiB           [emitted]
       App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/icon.png   73.8 KiB           [emitted]
       App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/drawable-xxxhdpi/logo.png    193 KiB           [emitted]
           App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values-v21/colors.xml  104 bytes           [emitted]
           App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values-v21/styles.xml  902 bytes           [emitted]
               App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/colors.xml  237 bytes           [emitted]
               App_Resources/Android/src/main/res/values/styles.xml   1.68 KiB           [emitted]
                                                          bundle.js     17 KiB   bundle  [emitted]  bundle
                                                       package.json   82 bytes           [emitted]
                                                         runtime.js   29.8 KiB  runtime  [emitted]  runtime
                                                         starter.js   60 bytes           [emitted]
                                                tns-java-classes.js    0 bytes           [emitted]
                                                          vendor.js   5.02 MiB   vendor  [emitted]  vendor
Entrypoint bundle = runtime.js vendor.js bundle.js
[../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy recursive] ../$$_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object 160 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app.css] 1.01 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.html] 167 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.component.ts] 354 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/app.module.ts] 1.71 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/menu/menu.component.css] 19 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/menu/menu.component.html] 1.11 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/menu/menu.component.ts] 933 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/services/dish.service.ts] 1.29 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./app/services/process-httpmsg.service.ts] 784 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./app/shared/baseurl.ts] 49 bytes {bundle} [built]
[./main.ts] 2.36 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./package.json] 73 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
    + 386 hidden modules
Webpack compilation complete. Watching for file changes.
Webpack build done!
Skipping prepare.
Successfully transferred runtime.js on device emulator-5554.
Restarting application on device emulator-5554...
Successfully synced application org.nativescript.conFusion on device emulator-5554.
JS: HMR: Hot Module Replacement Enabled. Waiting for signal.
System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.conFusion/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
System.err: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err:
System.err: Error: Template parse errors:
System.err: Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
System.err: </ActionBar>
System.err: <StackLayout class="page">
System.err:     [ERROR ->]<ListView [items]="dishes" class="list-group" *ngIf="dishes">
System.err:         <ng-template let-dish="item">
System.err: Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
System.err:         </ng-template>
System.err:     </ListView>
System.err:     [ERROR ->]<ActivityIndicator busy="true"  *ngIf="!(dishes || errMess)" width="50" height="50" class="activity-i"): ng:///AppModule/MenuComponent.html@14:4
System.err: Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("="!(dishes || errMess)" width="50" height="50" class="activity-indicator"></ActivityIndicator>
System.err:     [ERROR ->]<Label *ngIf="errMess" [text]="'Error: ' + errMess"></Label>
System.err: </StackLayout>"): ng:///AppModule/MenuComponent.html@15:4
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js, line: 21142, column: 12
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'ZoneAwareError', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 73853, column: 33
System.err:     Frame: function:'syntaxError', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 11620, column: 17
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 21142, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 36218, column: 37
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 36205, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 36148, column: 62
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 36148, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 36058, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'then', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 11611, column: 77
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 36057, column: 26
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 36017, column: 37
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 68387, column: 31
System.err:     Frame: function:'compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 62226, column: 21
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 62435, column: 16
System.err:     Frame: function:'_bootstrapper', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 71945, column: 35
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 72008, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js.Observable.notify', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 90899, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'notifyLaunch', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 109265, column: 17
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js.ActivityCallbacksImplementation.setActivityContent', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 109187, column: 28
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js.ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 109036, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 106850, column: 25
System.err:
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3260)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3396)
System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2009)
System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7319)
System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:934)
System.err: Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException:
System.err: Calling js method onCreate failed
System.err:
System.err: Error: Template parse errors:
System.err: Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
System.err: </ActionBar>
System.err: <StackLayout class="page">
System.err:     [ERROR ->]<ListView [items]="dishes" class="list-group" *ngIf="dishes">
System.err:         <ng-template let-dish="item">
System.err: Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("
System.err:         </ng-template>
System.err:     </ListView>
System.err:     [ERROR ->]<ActivityIndicator busy="true"  *ngIf="!(dishes || errMess)" width="50" height="50" class="activity-i"): ng:///AppModule/MenuComponent.html@14:4
System.err: Property binding ngIf not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("="!(dishes || errMess)" width="50" height="50" class="activity-indicator"></ActivityIndicator>
System.err:     [ERROR ->]<Label *ngIf="errMess" [text]="'Error: ' + errMess"></Label>
System.err: </StackLayout>"): ng:///AppModule/MenuComponent.html@15:4
System.err: File: "file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js, line: 21142, column: 12
System.err:
System.err: StackTrace:
System.err:     Frame: function:'ZoneAwareError', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 73853, column: 33
System.err:     Frame: function:'syntaxError', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 11620, column: 17
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 21142, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 36218, column: 37
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 36205, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 36148, column: 62
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 36148, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 36058, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'then', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 11611, column: 77
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 36057, column: 26
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/@angular/compiler/fesm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 36017, column: 37
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/fesm5/platform-browser-dynamic.js.CompilerImpl.compileModuleAsync', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 68387, column: 31
System.err:     Frame: function:'compileNgModuleFactory__PRE_R3__', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 62226, column: 21
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModule', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 62435, column: 16
System.err:     Frame: function:'_bootstrapper', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 71945, column: 35
System.err:     Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 72008, column: 19
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/observable.js.Observable.notify', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 90899, column: 23
System.err:     Frame: function:'notifyLaunch', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 109265, column: 17
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js.ActivityCallbacksImplementation.setActivityContent', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 109187, column: 28
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js.ActivityCallbacksImplementation.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 109036, column: 14
System.err:     Frame: function:'push.../node_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/activity.js.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js', line: 106850, column: 25
System.err:
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1203)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1083)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1070)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1050)
System.err:     at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1042)
System.err:     at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:19)
System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7783)
System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7772)
System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3235)
System.err:     ... 11 more
```

I know the emulator is exist in my computer and it will launch after I run the above command but shows many errors in the screen. As I am new in NativeScript and just following a video tutorial can't understand what is the problem? How can I fix it?

EDIT:
This is the content of `menu.component.html` file:

```
<ActionBar title="Menu" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout class="page">
    <ListView [items]="dishes" class="list-group" *ngIf="dishes">
        <ng-template let-dish="item">
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="list-group-item">
                <Image row="0" col="0" rowSpan="2" height="108" width="108"  [src]="BaseURL + dish.image" class="thumb p-16"></Image>
                <GridLayout class="list-group-item" rows="auto *" columns="*">
                    <Label row="0" col="0" [text]="dish.name" class="list-group-item-heading"></Label>
                    <Label row="1" col="0" class="list-group-item-text" [text]="dish.description"></Label>   
                </GridLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
    <ActivityIndicator busy="true"  *ngIf="!(dishes || errMess)" width="50" height="50" class="activity-indicator"></ActivityIndicator>
    <Label *ngIf="errMess" [text]="'Error: ' + errMess"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

EDIT2:
I solved the previous problem with the guides in comments but I see this new error in the emulator screen:

```
No ErrorHandler. Is platform module (BrowserModule) included?

Error: No ErrorHandler. Is platform module (BrowserModule) included?
    at file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js:62401:23 [angular]
    at Object.onInvoke (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js:61906:33) [angular]
    at NgZone.push.../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.run (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js:61820:28) [<root>]
    at PlatformRef.push.../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js:62396:23) [<root>]
    at file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js:62436:59 [<root>]
    at file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js:73438:34 [<root>]
    at Function.drainMicroTaskQueue (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.conFusion/files/app/vendor.js:73150:35) [<root>]
```

Comment: The error is telling you that there is an error in your `MenuComponent.html` xml template.  Specifically that you can't use `ngIf` directive inside an embedded  template.  Please post the full code of the MenuComponent.html file

Comment: Have you imported `CommonModule` into your module which actually enables access to directives like ngIf.

Comment: @Manoj: Where should I import it?

Comment: In your NgModule where you have declared the MenuComponent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must include `CommonModule` in your NgModule which actually enable support for common directives like ngIf.

Also it's obvious you can not import BrowserModule, you are not running your app in Browser here but the equivalent would be NativeScriptModule.

Comment: I am just following a tutorial video and it's their code. So I will search for that component and remove it and tell the result. Thanks.

Comment: May I ask which tutorial exactly?

Comment: Multiplatform mobile application on Coursera. I think it's for 2 years ago and some components and other things are changed

Comment: Could be, you would use NativeScriptModule which is alternative of Browser module. If it's multi platform project, you must consider having separate tns module file for using NativeScript specific modules.

Comment: I searched for `BrowserModule` and found that in the `vendor.js` file there are many of them! How can I fix that?

Comment: I use `tns create <projectName> --ng` similar to tutorial, but there are `-ts` and `-js` options I think as well. Maybe I must create a new project with those options and without `--ng` option?

Comment: I would say choose Angular only you are familiar with it. Go with JS / TS if you are not. Between, you wouldn't edit vendor.js as it's auto generated file.

Comment: So what should I do? maybe I must import `BrowserModule` to my project too?

Comment: No, I tried to add that module but gets a new error about `document is not defined`.

Comment: Have you included NativeScriptModule in app module, if not you should.

Comment: But it shows a new error on the screen: `ReferenceError: ErrorEvent is not defined.`

Comment: That doesn't sound anywhere related to this thread. Try opening a new thread with appropriate sample code if issue presists.

Comment: OK, I created a new issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56577315/error-referenceerror-errorevent-is-not-defined-for-nativescript-app