# "Error-ReferenceError-ErrorEvent is not defined" for NativeScript app

Tags: typescript, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am a new learner of NativeScript. I am following a video tutorial on Coursera to create an Android project using NativeScript, and I got the above error that is made by this part of my code:

`process-httpmsg.service.ts` :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProcessHTTPMsgService {

  constructor() { }

  public handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse | any) {
    let errMsg: string;

    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      errMsg = error.error.message;
    } else {
      errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${error.message}`;
    }

    return throwError(errMsg);
  }
}
```

`dish.services.ts`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { baseURL } from '../shared/baseurl';
import { ProcessHTTPMsgService } from './process-httpmsg.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DishService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,
    private processHTTPMsgService: ProcessHTTPMsgService) { }

  getDishes(): Observable<Dish[]> {
    return this.http.get<Dish[]>(baseURL + 'dishes')
      .pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
  }

  getDish(id: string): Observable<Dish> {
    return this.http.get<Dish>(baseURL + 'dishes/' + id)
      .pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
  }

  getFeaturedDish(): Observable<Dish> {
    return this.http.get<Dish[]>(baseURL + 'dishes?featured=true').pipe(map(dishes => dishes[0]))
      .pipe(catchError(this.processHTTPMsgService.handleError));
  }
}
```

`menu.component.html`:

```
<ActionBar title="Menu" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout class="page">
    <ListView [items]="dishes" class="list-group" *ngIf="dishes">
        <ng-template let-dish="item">
            <StackLayout orientation="horizontal" class="list-group-item">
                <Image row="0" col="0" rowSpan="2" height="108" width="108"  [src]="BaseURL + dish.image" class="thumb p-16"></Image>
                <GridLayout class="list-group-item" rows="auto *" columns="*">
                    <Label row="0" col="0" [text]="dish.name" class="list-group-item-heading"></Label>
                    <Label row="1" col="0" class="list-group-item-text" [text]="dish.description"></Label>   
                </GridLayout>
            </StackLayout>
        </ng-template>
    </ListView>
    <ActivityIndicator busy="true"  *ngIf="!(dishes || errMess)" width="50" height="50" class="activity-indicator"></ActivityIndicator>
    <Label *ngIf="errMess" [text]="'Error: ' + errMess"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

`menu.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Dish } from '../shared/dish';
import { DishService } from '../services/dish.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  moduleId: module.id,
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  dishes: Dish[];
  errMess: string;

  constructor(private dishService: DishService,
    @Inject('baseURL') private baseURL) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dishService.getDishes()
      .subscribe(dishes => this.dishes = dishes,
        errmess => this.errMess = <any>errmess);
  }

}
```

I don't know which other parts of the project's code is needed to put, so let me know that please.

EDIT:
`baseURL.ts`:

```
// export const baseURL = "http://localhost:3000/";

export const baseURL = "http://192.168.1.5:3000/";
```

Comment: Why you are checking whether it's ErrorEvent, ain't you suppose to check whether it's HttpErrorResponse?

Comment: This is the code of the tutorial, what do should I do?

Comment: @Manoj: I have added a new file of the project to my question.

Comment: @Manoj: After some days I understood what you say and changed the code to see the `HttpErrorResponse` error and it says: `Http failure response for http://localhost...`

Comment: My `json-server` is running on `http://localhost:3000` and the paths working when I checking them manually in my browser.

Answer (score 2):

As I already mentioned you can not do `error.error instanceof ErrorEvent` as `ErrorEvent` is an interface not class. You could do `error.error instanceof HttpErrorResponse`.

You can not hit `http://localhost:3000` from your Simulator / Emulator, you are suppose to hit your api by your machine's IP as they are in same network but technically different (simulated) devices.

Comment: So, what is the solution? What should I write in `baseURL` file that I have added it to my question too.

Comment: Please read the answer fully, i have already mentioned you should use IP address instead of localhost.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work: `export const baseURL = "http://192.168.1.5:3000/";`

Comment: I also tried `http://192.168.1.5:3000` on my browser but seems doesn't work! What is the problem?

Comment: Troubleshoot your server-issues first - if your browser can not access it by IP, your Emulator certainly can not, either.

Comment: This is code directly from the angular website. `const message = (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) ?
        error.error.message :
       `server returned code ${error.status} with body "${error.error}"`;`

Answer (score 2):

His code is straight from the Angular docs and his problem with `error.error instanceof ErrorEvent` is **not** that `ErrorEvent` is an interface not a class. Please see the reference to the relevant Angular documentation at the end.

His actual problem is that `ErrorEvent` is a Web API, which is not implemented in a NativeScript environment. This means if you were running your code in a browser it would work perfectly fine.

It seems like in NativeScript, a `HttpErrorResponse` is always returned but if it is a client-side or network issue (where a `ErrorEvent` would usually be returned), it sets the `status` to "0", and the `statusText` to "Unknown Error".

#### Angular Docs:

> Two types of errors can occur.
>
> The server backend might reject the request, returning an HTTP response with a status code such as 404 or 500. These are error responses.
>
> Something could go wrong on the client-side such as a network error that prevents the request from completing successfully or an exception thrown in an RxJS operator. These errors produce JavaScript ErrorEvent objects.
>
> https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-error-details

```js
private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
  if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
    // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
    console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
  } else {
    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.
    console.error(
      `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
      `body was: ${error.error}`);
  }
  // Return an observable with a user-facing error message.
  return throwError(
    'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few mistakes/ possible shortcoming in your code:

1. As @Manoj answered `error.error instanceof ErrorEvent` should be replaced by `error.error instanceof HttpErrorResponse`
2. Your menu.component.html uses `[src]="BaseURL + dish.image" >` it should be  `[src]="baseURL + dish.image" >` as you injected `baseURL`
3. You may need the nativescript wrapper for httpClient

```
import { NativeScriptHttpClientModule } from '@nativescript/angular/http-client';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
       ...
       NativeScriptHttpClientModule]
    ...
}]
```

3. Make sure that your `baseURL` server allow connection from possibly unsecure sources.
4. If you build nativescript app for Android check that your `AndroidManifest.xml` allows internet connections. Make sure the following are set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        ...
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```